# flask run Error: Could Not Import "App" and "App.py"

Tags: python, flask

Ran into a problem running Flask. Had it working before but something changed.
I go into my cmd and type flask run, and I get the usual:

```
Error: Could not import 'app'.
```

I googled around and found I could type in the following and it would work:

```
Set FLASK_APP=app.py 
Set FLASK_ENVIRONMENT=development
flask run
```

And now instead of saying it cannot import app, now it says it cannot import app.py.

My file structure is as follows:

```
newvenv:
| Include
| Lib
| Scripts
| | _pyrache_
| | static
| | templates
| | app.py
```

In the bottom of app.py I have included:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=30006, debug=True)
```

But it doesn't appear to be working.

I am on windows, and I know flask is finicky on it sometimes, but I don't think that's the cause of it. I'm lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `set FKASK_APP=Scripts/app.py`

Comment: That did it, thanks so much. If you want to post it as the answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to provide the full path of your `app.py` while setting the `FLASK_APP` environment.

`set FLASK_APP=Scripts/app.py`

Answer (score 0):

with app.py as my app

flask --app app run --debug

worked for me. Nothing else.

Comment: Please work on formatting your code to make it easier for everyone to read.